# Unity3D loading resources after build

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, resources, load

I have many sets of images (PNG) that are placed in different subfolders inside the `Resources` folder on the Assets of the project. When working on the editor I'm able to load the images from the different subfolders without a problem, by just simply use the `Resources.Load()` command and providing the path to the specific image that I'm trying to load, such as:

```
firstLeftCC = Resources.Load("Case2/Left/CC/IMG-0004-00001", typeof(Texture2D)) as Texture2D;
```

In this example the image "IMG-0004-00001" is placed in the CC folder, and the CC folder is inside the Left folder, and the Left folder is inside the Case2 folder, and finally the Case2 folder is in the Resources Folder.

But after building the project, for a Windows application, when I run the `.exe` file it doesn't load any of those images. After some research, it seems that the problem is related with the presence of the subfolders inside the Resources, since the path given to the Resources.Load() function to load the image doesn't exist in the build.

I would like to know if anyone knows a solution for this problem, or if it is possible to load the images from a given folder instead of trying to load them from the Resources folder.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What is folder you saved the image in? Update your question with the question is located. Where is "Case2" folder? Where is it in your editor. This will help people answer your question.

Comment: The image is in a subfolder inside the Resources folder, which is placed in the Assets folder of the project. In the example given, the image IMG-004-0001 is inside the CC folder, which is inside the Left folder, and so on, and the Case2 folder is within the Resources.

Comment: Case2 is in Assests folder and other folders are in Case2?

Comment: Case2 is inside the Resources folder, which is in the Assets folder. So its something like this: Assets - Resources - Case2 - Left - CC - IMG-0004-00001.png

Comment: I get it now. I dont see anything wrong with your code. I am coming up with another method to do this but those images must be outside Resources folder. Is this on Windows?

Comment: Yes it is on Windows

Comment: ok .will be back in a moment

Comment: I provided answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Optional** method of loading your PNG file during run time.
You can leave the **Case2** in the Asset Folder during development. **After** you build for Windows, go to folder the **exe** built file is. Let's assume it is called **Game.exe**. There will be a folder called **Game_Data** in the-same directory the **Game.exe** executable file is.

**Copy** the **Case2** folder to the **Game_Data** folder.

It should now look like this .... `Game_Data/Case2/Left/CC/IMG-0004-00001.PNG`

Now with code below, you can easily **read** your **png** files with the code below:

```
  Texture2D firstLeftCC = null;
    byte[] imageBytes;
    string imagePath = Application.dataPath + "/Case2/Left/CC/IMG-0004-00001.PNG";

    if (File.Exists(imagePath))
    {
        Debug.Log("Exist");
        imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
        firstLeftCC = new Texture2D(10, 10);
        firstLeftCC.LoadImage(imageBytes);
    }
```

Now you can freely use firstLeftCC as a Texture2D

**Note**: Unity creates .meta **file/folder** for every **file/folder** in the **Assets** directory. When when you copy the directory,**IMG-0004-00001.PNG** will have another file called **IMG-0004-00001.PNG.meta**. You should either NOT place your **Case2** folder in the Assets folder during development or you will have to **delete** these yourself.

Include `using System.IO;`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Resources.Load, you can load images from a given folder using the WWW class. To do this the URL must use the file:// protocol and contains the path to the files according to your OS.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/517414/how-to-use-www-to-load-local-files.html

Comment: Yes he can with the WWW class but the problem is that it requires coroutine and also he has to wait with isDone. using System.IO.File is quicker. So the code he posted above, if his program flow does not include coroutine, that would be little hard to convert his Resources.Load function code to coroutine code.