# Unity3D: Finding folder path when Building the project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, load, text-files

I am extracting some information from several text files in different folders. For that purpose I created an application with several Input Fields to write the folders' name that I want to go. Everything went well in Editor Mode.

However when I **build the project** and run the ".exe" file created, it can't find the text files I want. I show below the code I am using to extract the files. The **first data.path** is the one I used on my Editor and worked well while the **second (commented) data.path** is one trial that I tried by placing my folder on the ".exe" Data folder. But it didn't work...

```
data.motion = input_text;
data.subjectName = input_text2;

data.path = "C:/Users/Matias/Desktop/Acquisition_Data/Kinect1/" + data.subjectName + "/" + data.motion + ".txt";
/*data.path = Application.dataPath + "/Acquisition_Data/Kinect1/" + data.subjectName + "/" + data.motion + ".txt";*/

data.lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(data.path);
```

I can't get any explanation why any of these methods work when I build the application.

I am using C# and running on Windows10.

Comment: you can only use `Application.persistentDataPath` and that's it. never use anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't do that because Unity **encodes** the files into **binary** form and **renames** them too. You have to move the txt file after building then you can access it directly.  I answered similar question like this yesterday so I will post the link to the answer. Do do things I mentioned in this answer below.

[Unity3D loading resources after build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016350/unity3d-loading-resources-after-build/36021470#36021470)

Then **remove** the **Texture2D** stuff and **replace** `File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);` with `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(data.path);` and that should work.

Comment: It should world. It worked for me, worked the other person that question the question. You probably did something wrong somewhere. Good to know that you got it working.

Comment: I followed your instructions but it didn't work in building. However this new script works in Editor after I moved the Acquisition_Data folder to the Assets. Besides I couldn't use the ReadAllLines as you suggest due to being bytes[] and not string so I did: `fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(data.path);` then `aux_string = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(fileBytes);` and finally `data.lines = Regex.Split(aux_string, "\r\n");`

Comment: "I couldn't use the ReadAllLines as you suggest due to being bytes[] and not string so I did".You are suppose to make to make a little bit change there and that's not compicated. Also ReadAllBytes would have worked too but since you used ReadAllLines in your question, I told you to change ReadAllBytes to ReadAllLines for text. I still think that you moved it to the wrong folder and that's why my method didnt work for you.You are also suppose to modify the url and change the extension to txt.  Since you got it working, there is nothing more to talk about. congrats.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of using Relative path or using absolute path.
If absolute path doesn't work try relative path. 
eg. 
../name.txt

put your name.txt in asset or somewhere you can point with.

Answer (score 0):

If your texts are static (never more, never less) then you could simply use TextAsset : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html

1. Make prefabs from text assets;
2. Put the prefabs into your scene;
3. Let the user what prefab(s) to load text(s) from.